# C# Comparing values in 2 DataTables

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, datatable, compare

I'm processing 2 DataTables:

1. SSFE: Contains the values I want to find
2. FFE: Is larger, smaller or equally large as SSFE, but does not necessarily contain every value of SSFE

The values I need to match between these tables are integers, both tables are sorted from small to large.
My idea was to start searching on the first item in FFE, start looping through SSFE, and when I find a match -> remember current index -> save match -> select next item from FFE and continue from the previous index.

Also FFE can contain integers, but can also contain strings, that is why I cast the values to a string and compare these.

I made some code, but it takes, too much time.
It will take about a minute to compare SSFE(1.000 items) to FFE(127.000) items.

```
int whereami = 0;
bool firstiteration = true;
for (int i = 0; i < FFEData.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SSFEData.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (firstiteration)
        {
            j = whereami;
            firstiteration = false;
        }
        if (SSFEData.Rows[j][0] == FFEData.Rows[i][0].ToString())
        {
            found++;
            whereami = j;
            firstiteration = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only storing how many occurences I have found for testing. In this example it will find 490 matches, not that this is relevant.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: [codereview.se] might like this question a bit more than SO.  That said, things like `ToString` strike me as inefficient, also, the `where` variable is not clear what its supposed to do, but I'd bet that the `firstiteration` test could be removed with a few logic changes.

Comment: Additionally, I've found that datatables are quite slow.  If this data was populated into your own objects, you could use linq to join the two together and find the matches.  This would not be a speed up, but it would make your code much more readable.

Comment: @paqogomez The were is a local variable that stores the current index, 'j' in this case. The data is in fact populated in my own objects, joining the 2 tables via Linq is not an option. Because the application must be as short as possible, this is because it runs on (very) important production servers which do not have a lot of RAM left for complicated and long running tasks. Currently is uses about 200MB of RAM, when doing this Linq procedure it will build up to about 600MB wich is too much.

Comment: Why not have your inner loop do this?  `DataRow[] result = FFEData.Select("itemid == " + SSFEData.Rows[j][0]'); if (result.Count > 0) found++;`  Then you only loop your small dataset.  Be sure to index your data table column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try the DataRelation class. It creates a foreign key / join between two DataTables in a DataSet.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

public int GetMatches(DataTable table1, DataTable table2)
{
    DataSet set = new DataSet();

    //wrap the tables in a DataSet.
    set.Tables.Add(table1);
    set.Tables.Add(table2);

    //Creates a ForeignKey like Join between two tables.
    //Table1 will be the parent. Table2 will be the child.
    DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("IdJoin", table1.Columns[0], table2.Columns[0], false);

    //Have the DataSet perform the join.
    set.Relations.Add(relation);

    int found = 0;

    //Loop through table1 without using LINQ.
    for(int i = 0; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //If any rows in Table2 have the same Id as the current row in Table1
        if (table1.Rows[i].GetChildRows(relation).Length > 0)
        {
            //Add a counter
            found++;

            //For debugging, proof of match:
            //Get the id's that matched.
            string id1 = table1.Rows[i][0].ToString();

            string id2 = table1.Rows[i].GetChildRows(relation)[0][0].ToString();

        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

I randomly populated two non-indexed tables with nvarchar(2) strings, with 10,000 rows each.  The match took sub 1 second, including the time spent populating the tables.  I would get between 3500 and 4000 matches a run on average.

However, the major caveat is that the DataColumns being matched *must* be the same data type.  So if both columns are string, or at least integers stored as string, then this will work.

But if one column is an integer, you will have to add a new column, and store the integers as string in that column first.  The string translations will add a hefty amount of time.

Another option will be uploading the tables to a database and performing a query.  That large an upload will probably take a few seconds, but the query will be under one second as well. So still better than 60 seconds+.

Comment: This works like a charm! The comparing will now actually take less time than running the query that fills them. Thanks!